# Mount new disk to existing root mountpoint using mhddfs (merging filesystems)

Tags: filesystems, mount, disk, root-filesystem

I have a new disk on server (`sdb`) and I want to mount it to existing root mountpoint (`sda1` mounted on `/`) to merge it. There is an utility called [mhddfs](https://romanrm.net/mhddfs) which is doing exactly what I want. But the problem is in examples is shown mounting existing mountpoints to one merged called `virtual` which isn't used before:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1              80G   50G   30G  63% /mnt/hdd1
/dev/sdb1              40G   35G    5G  88% /mnt/hdd2
/dev/sdc1              60G   10G   50G  17% /mnt/hdd3
$ mkdir /mnt/virtual
$ mhddfs /mnt/hdd1,/mnt/hdd2,/mnt/hdd3 /mnt/virtual -o allow_other
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1              80G   50G   30G  63% /mnt/hdd1
/dev/sdb1              40G   35G    5G  88% /mnt/hdd2
/dev/sdc1              60G   10G   50G  17% /mnt/hdd3
mhddfs                180G   95G   85G  53% /mnt/virtual
```

But my filesystem looks like this:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        76G   58G   15G  80% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  8.7M  3.2G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1008
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1007
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       197G  188M  187G   1% /mnt/sdb1
```

and these are the disks:

```
$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 101 GiB, 108447924224 bytes, 211812352 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ced15

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048 204000000 203997953 97.3G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       204001280 211812351   7811072  3.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       204003328 211812351   7809024  3.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 200 GiB, 214748364800 bytes, 419430400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 145F5C99-D238-4702-B728-04A613B1DBA1

Device     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 419428351 419426304  200G Linux filesystem
```

So how to mount `sdb1` to `/` with `mhddfs`? Can I just do this like in example:

```
$ mhddfs /,/mnt/sda1 / -o allow_other
```

Of course I don't want to lose existing data on `sda` and I am not sure what will `mhddfs` do in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a warning: I have no experience with mhddfs, but  there are a few general rules:

All examples of mentioned in the mhddfs readme are based on mounting a new mountpoint - not an existing one.

So just putting an overlay over an already mounted point is not mentioned.

Also consider what you are doing at that point: 
/dev/sda1 looks pretty much like your boot and root partition.

Even if you are able to remount it with any tool - how you know that the right files are getting added for new linux-kernels ?

My advice would be: 
Figure out which directories are getting quite large. Try to move out this directory to the new drive.

Based on your example: 
`$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        76G   58G   15G  80% /
/dev/sdb1       197G  188M  187G   1% /mnt/sdb1
[...]`

Try: 
`sudo du -hs /*`

You may end up with 50GB of stuff in /home

If so, you can copy everything from /home to /mnt/sdb1/ 
if you have done that:
umount /dev/sdb1 
rename /home to /home_old 
mkdir /home 
and mount /dev/sdb1 to /home

this new mountpoint will be configured in /etc/fstab:

As you can see: you need no magic extra tools - this is standard unix admin work ;-)

Comment: Thanks. This server is hosting several Counter-Strike: GO servers so `/home` is biggest directory and also in `/var` is some shared data for these game servers. So you are suggesting that OS should be on its own partition (or disk)? I can surely do what you wrote, but the OS self is not much big so the `sda1` won't be used a lot if I move game servers to `sdb1`.

Comment: I would suggest to move the largest part to the second harddisk. 

Maybe it is enough to move /home (based on your results of the " du -hs /* "  . You can still move other larger parts (i.e. /var/lib ) to the second disk or even a third disk later on. 

If you add the partition to fstab, you can choose to either use the /dev/sdX naming convention or (more modern) the UUID of the partition. You can get the UUID of all partitions via the command: blkid

Comment: OK, seems like the easiest solution. Thanks for help :) I will accept your answer if nobody else answer.